# require index results undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, require

I have two folders next to each other as it follows ..

```
// Folder 1 
users
-services
-index
-otherThings

= services
exports.A = (a,b,c)=> { // do something }
exports.B = (a,b,c)=> { // do something }

= index.js
const services= require('./services');
const otherThings= require('./otherThings');
module.exports = { otherThings, services};


// Folder 2
middlewares
-is-auth
-index.js

= is-auth 
const { services } = require('../users');
// services here is undefined
// when i require the full index object it is an empty object
const indexObject = require('../users')
console.log(indexObject) // {}
```

the weird thing is when using services required above i am getting suggestions of the folder 1 services (A,B functions) but they are undefined !

Comment: What is the _users_ directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. console log services in folder 1 if it is coming there.
2. check the hierarchy of your folder structures when importing and
   check the paths also,

other wise the code seems right.

**edit 1:**

3. not sure what exactly services type are, but it seems only function A and B are there, if you just need those functions you can export them individually and try,

if that works then you can back track to, why services was not working in the first place,

4. if not, then just try any random variable try importing if it doesn't work then it's may be related to hierarchy.

**edit 2:**

- i think i got it,
  if my assumption is right users is folder and services is file, then you need the path as **require(../users/services);**

**edit 3:**

then check out this link [require folder as  a module](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_folders_as_modules)

Comment: I am requiring other packages in the services is that the thing that results this

Comment: nested imports should not be the case if the folder structure is right, but its not like we can import where ever we want, but hey i just noticed, as you have mentioned you need just A and B functions and you are exporting it why not directly import it.

Comment: Thanks for your attenetion ..
it works if i do it this way `require(../users/services);`
but i was doing the whole `index.js` for situation like this where i dont have to add the file name (only the folder and then the index.js targets the require ) and get my files from destructring the index.js requires

Comment: i have added a link in edit, that might be what you're looking for